# What do you set in the "column" field for adding a minimum words validation via the Field Validation module?

Tags: 7, entities

I'm creating a validation rule on a text field via the [Field Validation](http://drupal.org/project/field_validation) module. On the create screen it asks for "Column" and includes this description:

> A column defined in the hook_field_schema() of this field.

I do not understand what I need to enter here. Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may help you out....

**Field > Appropriate column value**

- Normal field > "value"
- Taxonomy field > "tid"
- Date field > "value" and "value2"
- Node reference field > "nid"
- User reference field > "uid"
- Link field > "url","title","attributes"